# Error Unknown security using Remote PSSession CredSSP

Tags: security, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have Windows 7 64 bits, and Powershell 2.0, and CredSSP enabled in client

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer * -Force
```

I open Powershell Console, and I execute Enter-PSSession command to connect Windows 2008 Server using CredSSP authentication:

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerMOSS -Authentication Credssp -Credential MyDomain\installerUser
```

I want execute Get-WSManCredSSP command remotely, but I get error: "... while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security error occurred."

```
PS C:\Users\myUser> Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerMOSS -Authentication Credssp -Credential MyDomain\installerUser

[ServerMOSS]: PS C:\Users\installerUser\Documents> Get-WSManCredSSP

WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security
 error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or us
e HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config.
    + CategoryInfo          :
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.GetWSManCredSSPCommand

[ServerMOSS]: PS C:\Users\installerUser\Documents> Exit-PSSession
```

IT departament execute this command in ServerMOSS:

```
PS C:\Users\installerUser\Documents> enabled-psremoting -force
```

and they get error:

```
WinRM already is set upt to receive requests on this machine
Set-WSManQuickConfig: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security error ocurred.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: check this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;970923

Comment: @CB. support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;970923  not found

Comment: I have found _https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970923_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue. I have searched and found several times that checking/setting the SPNs can solve the issue:

So try this:
To review (read only)

```
setspn.exe -L MACHINENAME
```

Review the results for HTTP/HTTPS entries (or any duplicates as well)

Add missing names:

```
setspn -A HTTP/machinename
setspn -A HTTP/machinename.fqdn.com
setspn -A HTTPS/machinename
setspn -A HTTPS/machinename.fqdn.com
```

Source: [WinRM QuickConfig failing with 0x8033809D](http://blog.chrislehr.com/2012/06/winrm-quickconfig-failing-with.html)

Comment: This DID work, however I could not find anything using the -L parameter, but I had to query directly the SPN using **setspn –q http/COMPUTERNAME**

Answer (score 0):

It is due to HTTPS/HTTP entries are not registered with the SPN.
Just do the following open Powershell as admin :

*Check the SPN entries with the command:*

PS C:\> setspn -L domainname\servername

*Then to add HTTP/HTTPS enteries do:*

1. PS C:\> setspn -A HTTP/servername servername
2. PS C:\> setspn -A HTTP/servername.fqdn.com servername
3. PS C:\> setspn -A HTTPS/servername servername
4. PS C:\> setspn -A HTTPS/servername.fqdn.com servername

THen finally you can use **Enable-PSRemoting -Force** on PowerShell prompt